# py2exe bash command to compile in Windows

Tags: windows, bash, python-3.x, exe, py2exe

The bash command:

> py script.py py2exe

just compile the file script.py and does not create the executable.

I managed to find the right bash command and it was something like:

> py -3.4 -m "I-do-not-remember" script.py

It worked, it correctly created the folder with the executable but I do not remember anymore the command and I haven not been able to find it anymore.

Which was the "I-do-not-remember" command?

Answer (score 0):

py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe myscript.py